# Web application using Python3 not working when Dockerized

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask

### HelloWorld-1.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def printHelloWorld():
    print("+++++++++++++++++++++")
    print("+ HELLO WORLD-1 +")
    print("+++++++++++++++++++++")
    return '<h1>Bishwajit</h1>'
    # return '<h1>Hello %s!<h1>' %name

if name == '__main__':
    app.run(debug='true')
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ADD HelloWorld-1.py /HelloWorld-1.py
RUN pip install flask
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "python", "/HelloWorld-1.py"]
```

Building docker using the below command

```
docker build -t helloworld .
```

Running docker image using below command

```
docker run -d --name helloworld -p 80:80 helloworld
```

when i run the below command

```
docker ps -a
```

i get the below output

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE      COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS             PORTS               NAMES

cebfe8a22493 helloworld "python /home/HelloW…" 2 minutes ago Up 2 minutes (unhealthy) 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp helloworld
```

If I hit in the browser(127.0.0.1:5000), it does not give response,
But when i run the python file individually, it runs properly in the browser.

Comment: you are trying to access by using `127.0.0.1:5000` so shouldn't the `-p` argument be as `-p 5000:80`?

Comment: i tried changing the port also, it did not work. Is my docker file correct?

Comment: i tried with that too..

In Dockerfile....it is there EXPOSE 80, should it be changed.

Comment: @programandoconro Finally it worked.
I changed few things
like
```
app.run(debug='true', port='5000', host='0.0.0.0')
```

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 helloworld
```

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your problem and there were four main problems:

1. Not importing `flask`.
2. Using `name` instead of `__name__`
3. Not assigning the correct port.
4. Not assigning the host.

This is how your `HelloWorld-1.py` should look like:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def printHelloWorld():
    print("+++++++++++++++++++++")
    print("+ HELLO WORLD-1 +")
    print("+++++++++++++++++++++")
    return '<h1>Bishwajit</h1>'
    # return '<h1>Hello %s!<h1>' %name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

This is how you `Dockerfile` should look like:

```
FROM python:3
ADD HelloWorld-1.py .
RUN pip install flask
CMD [ "python", "/HelloWorld-1.py"]
```

Then simply build and run:

```
docker build . -t helloflask
docker run -dit -p 5000:5000 helloflask
```

Now go to `localhost:5000` and it should work.

Additionally: You could actually assign any other port, for example 4444, and  then go to `localhost:4444`:

```
docker run -dit -p 4444:5000 helloflask
```

Comment: In Dockerfile....it is there EXPOSE 80, should it be changed.

Comment: Yes. correct .. If at all i want to expose a port, it need to first give the port, and expose it in Dockerfile.